# Nicely print "public" methods of python class

Tags: python, introspection, pretty-print

I am trying to design an API in python using a class:

```
class SimulationApi(object):

  def hello(self):
    return "Hi"

  def echo(self, string):
    return string

  def get_foo(self):
    return self.foo

  def __init__(self):
    self.foo = 50
```

And i'd like to print to console a list of available public methods defined by the class. Is there a way to to this automatically, that will also pick up the method parameters? Ideally, the output would look like this:

```
SimulationApi: 
    get_foo()
    echo(string)
    hello()
```

So far, my solution is this, but it is not complete and may be the wrong direction.

```
print("SimulationApi: \n\t{}\n".format("\n\t".join([x+"()" for x in dir(SimulationApi) if not x.startswith("__")]))
```

Comment: Actually, this is not bad at all ! Just be aware there is already the `help` method that might be useful instead of recoding

Comment: Can you not just use a documentation tool like sphinx?

Comment: That's good for the next iteration of the api, I was wondering if there was an easy way to get the parameters into there for the first stage. If there are useful tools in sphinx for the very early stages of APIs then that could work as well.

Comment: You want the pydoc module (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pydoc.html) - it's the module that supports the builtin `help` system and it knows how to generate text and html doc from the class / functions definitions and docstrings.

Comment: Maybe you would like to generate automatically the `__doc__` attribute with a metaclass?

Comment: In python all methods are public in general. You can access all of them from object. There are just conventions about private methods/variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module:

```
class SimulationApi(object):

  def hello(self):
    return "Hi"

  def echo(self, string):
    return string

  def get_foo(self):
    return self.foo

  def __init__(self):
    self.foo = 50


import inspect
inspect.getmembers(SimulationApi)
```

---

Will return:

```
[('__class__', type),
 ('__delattr__', <slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__dict__',
  mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__',
                'hello': <function __main__.SimulationApi.hello(self)>,
                'echo': <function __main__.SimulationApi.echo(self, string)>,
                'get_foo': <function __main__.SimulationApi.get_foo(self)>,
                '__init__': <function __main__.SimulationApi.__init__(self)>,
                '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'SimulationApi' objects>,
                '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'SimulationApi' objects>,
                '__doc__': None})),
 ('__dir__', <method '__dir__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__doc__', None),
 ('__eq__', <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__format__', <method '__format__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__ge__', <slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__getattribute__', <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__gt__', <slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__hash__', <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__init__', <function __main__.SimulationApi.__init__(self)>),
 ('__init_subclass__', <function SimulationApi.__init_subclass__>),
 ('__le__', <slot wrapper '__le__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__lt__', <slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__module__', '__main__'),
 ('__ne__', <slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__new__', <function object.__new__(*args, **kwargs)>),
 ('__reduce__', <method '__reduce__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__reduce_ex__', <method '__reduce_ex__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__repr__', <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__setattr__', <slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__sizeof__', <method '__sizeof__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__str__', <slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>),
 ('__subclasshook__', <function SimulationApi.__subclasshook__>),
 ('__weakref__', <attribute '__weakref__' of 'SimulationApi' objects>),
 ('echo', <function __main__.SimulationApi.echo(self, string)>),
 ('get_foo', <function __main__.SimulationApi.get_foo(self)>),
 ('hello', <function __main__.SimulationApi.hello(self)>)]
```

Note: Your methods (the methods you like to get info) are also the `SimulationApi` class dictionary `__dict__`.

You can get the full code for your `echo` function like this:

```
import inspect
lines = inspect.getsource(SimulationApi.echo)
print(lines)
```

---

```
  def echo(self, string):
    return string
```